# How to set value to default choice in Wicket DropDownChoice

Tags: java, user-interface, wicket-6

I need to create a wicket dropdownchoice component, I can replace default "Choose One" text to "All" by set

```
nullValid=All
null=All
```

in its properties file. I also want to set the value of "All" to -1, but could not get it done.

```
<select>
<option selected="selected" value>All</option>
<option value="1">Not Started</option>
<option value="2">In Progress</option>
<option value="3">Complete</option>
</select>
```

what i want is

```
<select>
<option selected="selected" value="-1">All</option>
<option value="1">Not Started</option>
<option value="2">In Progress</option>
<option value="3">Complete</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you have to setup the DropDownChoice to *not* allow `null` value and add `-1` to your list of allowed/possible values.
Finally you have to instantiate it with: `new DropDownChoice("compId", Model.of(-1), Arrays.asList(-1, 1, 2, 3), choiceRenderer)`, i.e. `-1` should be set as the default model object, so it is `selected` in the markup.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: In this way, the display is correct, But after form is submitted, the value in the dropdown is not taken. The value is always null. The first model seems causes the problem.

Comment: There must be something wrong in the submit process. Do you see a proper value submitted for the select element ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you got martin point . I am going to give some simple solution which will resolve your issue. 
let's  assume you have `SelectionOption` class which you have `key` and `value`

```
public class SelectOption {
    private String key;
    private String value;

    public SelectOption(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
     // getter and setter
}
```

Create a simple list of selectOptions and pass to the dropdownchoice

```
List<SelectOption> selectOptions = new ArrayList<>();
        selectOptions.add(new SelectOption("-1","ALL"));
        selectOptions.add(new SelectOption("1","Not Started"));
        selectOptions.add(new SelectOption("2","In Progress"));
        selectOptions.add(new SelectOption("3","Completed"));
```

//Simply  `override` choiceRender option to `show` key and `value` . I have override `getDefaultChoice` to remove select one(Its my convenient) since you removed already .

```
        add(new DropDownChoice("selectOption", selectOptions,new ChoiceRenderer<SelectOption>("value","key"){
            @Override
            public Object getDisplayValue(SelectOption object) {
                return object.getValue();
            }

            @Override
            public String getIdValue(SelectOption object, int index) {
                return object.getKey();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected CharSequence getDefaultChoice(String selectedValue) {
                return "";
            }
        });
```

Output:

```
<select wicket:id="selectOption" name="selectOption">
<option value="-1">ALL</option>
<option value="1">Not Started</option>
<option value="2">In Progress</option>
<option value="3">Completed</option>
</select>
```